# iteration over a twodimensional tuple and assigning inline (Python, iPython)

Tags: sql, loops, for-loop, tuples, ipython

I have something like (in my iPython notebook, no special namespaces like numpy included - should I?):

```
map1 = (("A",1,2),("B",4,5),("C",0,0))

print len(map1)

for i in range(len(map1)):
    name = map1[i][0]
    ID = map1[i][1]
    parent_ID = map1[i][2]
    print name, ID, parent_ID
    statement= "INSERT INTO map VALUES (" + name + "," + `ID` + "," + `parent_ID` + ")"
    print statement
```

I'm seeking for a more elegant way to extract the singe tuple elements as a oneliner or inliner. (took me long enough to figure out that the "`" does the toString() conversion )

Answer (score 1):

Python can multi assign, and extract within a loop.

```
for name, item_id, parent_id in map1:
  print name, item_id, parent_id
  statement= "INSERT INTO map VALUES (" + name + "," + `item_id` + "," + `parent_id` + ")"
  print statement
```

If you feel the string part lacks elegance, there are a couple of ways to tackle that. First - you can always use `str(item_id)` to get a string.

You can also use string formats:

```
  statement= "INSERT INTO map VALUES (%s, %d, %d)" % (name, item_id, parent_id)
```

On a final note - python conventions suggest lowercase for variable names (use uppercase if you intend to use it as a const value). The name "id" in lowercase is a builtin - don't use it, hence `item_id`.

```
for name, item_id, parent_id in map1:
  print name, item_id, parent_id
  statement= "INSERT INTO map VALUES (%s, %d, %d)" % (name, item_id, parent_id)
  print statement
```

You could even go one step further and use a list comprehension to do it all in one line:

```
statements = ["INSERT INTO map VALUES (%s, %d, %d)" % (name, item_id, parent_id) for name, item_id, parent_id in map1]
```

You now have an array of these statements to print, or use somewhere else.